# Changes to Terminal in El Capitan

Tags: terminal, tmux

Can someone please describe the changes made to Terminal.app in El Capitan? I've just noticed that mouse events started working in Tmux, which is awesome!

I had the following set in my `tmux.conf`:

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

which did not work because Terminal prior to OS X 10.11 did not pass mouse events to underlying processes. Now it wonderfully works. What other changes are included in new Terminal?

Comment: Not a 10.11 feature, but I noticed that `less` recognizes mouse scrolling sometime around 10.9 or 10.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new **Marks** feature in El Capitan 10.11 Terminal adds structure to the terminal contents by marking prompt lines and other interesting content, enabling operations like navigating, selecting, Copying, Printing and deleting commands or their output.

See the **Edit** menu, especially the **Marks**, **Bookmarks**, and **Navigation** submenus for Marks-related commands.

Marks are indicated with “square brackets” at either end of a marked line. Bookmarks are a more heavyweight mark—they're used for marking sections with a time stamp or a custom name—and are indicated with thicker vertical lines and a different background color.

You can hide the mark indicators if you don't want to see them, with the **View > Hide/Show Marks** menu item. This doesn't remove marks or prevent the Marks-related commands from working.

A good explanation of what you can do with Marks and the related commands is found in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209907/6883) to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/).

Comment: Ahh, a beautiful feature indeed. However (which is perhaps natural) marks do not work in tmux.

Comment: Marks do not work in the alternate screen, because its content is disconnected from the terminal scrollback. More specifically, tmux (and screen) are virtual terminals with their own scrollback buffers, which Terminal knows nothing about. If you marked a line in tmux it wouldn't be connected with the tmux content.

Answer (score 5):

The command lines are now marked with square brackets as in the screen snippet below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There's much more to this than square brackets. Those are "marks", and there are a bunch of references to them in the edit menu. You can add and remove marks, and use them to move around, select or clear output. And you can hide the bracket from the view menu but still get the functionality.