# Copy to clipboard from Tmux in El Capitan

Tags: terminal, tmux

I am quite happy with the Terminal changes in El Capitan (see e.g. [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208384/changes-to-terminal-in-el-capitan)).

However, i can't figure out how to enable copying to system clipboard from within Tmux. For instance, now that I am able to select text within Tmux properly by mouse, how can i copy selected text to clipboard as well, in addition to Tmux's own buffer?

I have the following in my `tmux.conf`:

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on

setw -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

I tried modifying the last line to

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection \; copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```

but it didn't really work. Would be grateful for suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: Cmd-C doesn't work?

Comment: @partix - no, as copied text is auto-deselected after releasing the mouse button (or trackpad). Of course it does work in Terminal, but not from Tmux within terminal.

Comment: Update to Tmux 2.1 broke mouse scrolling in Tmux panes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, i was wrong when stating that `copy-pipe` does not work. It does, and `copy-selection` is then superfluous, as `copy-pipe` both copies text to Tmux pasteboard and pipes to an arbitrary shell command. So the following line works:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```

However, one needs to press `y` before releasing the mouse button. I've stumbled across this in the documentation for [tmux-yank](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank) plugin:

"When making a selection using tmux mode-mouse on or mode-mouse copy-mode,   you cannot rely on the default 'release mouse after selection to copy' behavior. Instead, press y before releasing mouse."

So it works, but with somewhat annoying need to press `y` in order to copy mouse-selected text.

Comment: If you are using Terminal.app: in macOS Sierra this won't work due to regression in the Terminal.app behaviour. You will need to use "reattach-to-user-namespace" hack again.

Comment: Agree on @m1keil comment. Moreover, for some reason i had to compile reattach-to-user-namespace with additional switches, like this: `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace --with-wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste` (i am using Homebrew)

Answer (score 39):

Actually, I just find out very simple solution how to enable copying using Cmd+C again.

In default Terminal application go to View->"Allow mouse reporting" and uncheck it. Thats it.

PS: Obviously, the new nice features like dragging split screen in tmux stop working after unchecking the mouse reporting.

Comment: PS: I used previously solution from @siphiuel, which works also fine.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is the simplest way! Only that the history is broken.I can only see part of hitstory

Comment: Super nice. This works

Comment: and this also works for a remote tmux session; I'm thinking that the `bind-key ... copy-pipe` solution might only work if it's a local tmux session.  Then again, maybe if you do the remote tmux session within a local tmux session, it might work?  Anyway, unchecking "Allow mouse reporting" worked for me, and there's even a shortcut ⌘-R (Cmd-R) so that you can quickly toggle it off to make a copy, then back on again.

Comment: Thanks for the ⌘-R (Cmd-R) shortcut - that helps a lot!

Answer (score 26):

If you use iTerm2 3.x, you can make copy / paste work by enabling `Applications in terminal may access clipboard`:

[image]

Just highlight text with your mouse to copy it into the OS X clipboard!

You can also paste from the OS X clipboard into tmux with the usual <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: this was the easiest solution for me.

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 23):

If you hold the function key down you can select and copy to clipboard with apple+c as well.

Comment: We are looking for something more than a single line answer.  Try expanding your answer to give further detail.

Comment: @Allan This is a complete answer, even though it's just a single line. It's that simple.

Comment: btw, I found it only works on the laptop keyboard, not attached keyboards :(

Answer (score 5):

Using tmux version 2.2 or later add the following to your tmux.conf file:

```
bind-key -t emacs-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```

Comment: Works for El Capitan 10.11, tmux 2.7

Answer (score 5):

The answer of @Oplatek take effect

> In default Terminal application go to View->"Allow mouse reporting" and uncheck it.

But by this way, we would not be able to scroll the screen by mouse.

Here's another way without disable `Allow mouse reporting`:

Press `Fn` and select the text by mouse. It keeps the selection there so you can right click and select copy.

Answer (score 1):

Using tmux 2.2, OS X El Capitan, Terminal Version 2.6.1 (the default that ships with El Capitan), the following setup works flawless (so far).

```
$ cat ~/.tmux.conf
set -g mouse on
bind-key -t emacs-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```

To copy, press the left mouse button, mark the text, and let go. The marked text is then in the clipboard and can be pasted with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Check [ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard: Notes and workarounds for accessing the Mac OS X pasteboard in tmux sessions.](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard)

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Then add to `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

Answer (score -2):

i find only one way

open terminal settings/profiles in terminal info change terminal type from xterm-256 to ansi open new terminal window and enjoy :)