# New shortcut for going up one line in Terminal in El Capitan

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I upgraded to El Capitan a few days ago. Before I used to use ⌘+⬆︎ to go up exactly one line in the terminal (and usually pressed the combination continuously to go exactly were I wanted), but this doesn't work in El Capitan. What is the new shortuct ? This is not covered AFAIK in this other [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208384/changes-to-terminal-in-el-capitan) which is more about marks.

Comment: Still seems to work on Mine. Never used it before, but I get the line flash highlight

Comment: Under the View menu in Terminal, it lists Option-Command-PageUp/PageDown to go up/down a line (which on my keyboard with a function key but no Page Up/Down keys, ends up being Fn-Option-Command-Up/Down).